# Rails Select Box for fixed values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have a fixed Select box that gives an option of 1 to 5. Where 3 is the Default when the page loads.

```
<%= f.select(:priority, ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'], {:selected => '3'}, {:class=>'chzn-select', :style => 'width:350px'}) %>
```

Now when someone selects 4 and submits the form it should retain the value if there was a form validation error and the form is displayed.

My code doesnt seem to retail the value once the form is submitted and has a validation error.

Comment: Well, fix the error and un-hardcode the `:selected` value

Comment: Try `{:selected => params[:my_object][:priority] || '3'}`. Where `:my_object` is the object for which you are building the `form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're wrapping an object with `form_for`, the values set into that object are what will/should appear in the form fields. So you should be getting the behavior you want automatically. The problem seems to be that you're overriding that behavior by setting a `selected` option in the helper which is hardcoding the select element in the html.

### Option 1

Use [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) to specify the values and the default selected option:

```
<%= f.select(:priority, options_for_select(['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'], 3), 
                        {}, 
                        class: "chzn-select",
                        style: "width: 350px" %>
```

In this way, the default option (`3`) is passed as the second argument to `options_for_select` and is only used when `f.object.priority` is not already initialized.

### Option 2

Another (good) option is to not set a default selected value in the view, but rather in the controller when you're initializing your object:

```
def new
  @my_object = MyObject.new(priority: 3)
end

def create
  @my_object = MyObject.new(my_object_params)
  if @my_object.save
    # ...
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

This way, when the form loads the `form_for` will wrap your object (`@my_object`) and be defaulted to `3` again. And in the `create` action whatever the user set it to will be set instead, keeping the user's selection when re-rendering the form again with validation errors.

With this approach, your form would look like this:

```
<%= form_for @my_object do %>
  <%= f.select(:priority, options_for_select(['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']), 
                          {}, 
                          class: "chzn-select", style: "width: 350px" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass dynamic value to be selected.

Try something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@my_object) do %>
  ...
  <%= f.select(:priority, ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1'], {:selected => params[:my_object][:priority] || '3'}, {:class=>'chzn-select', :style => 'width:350px'}) %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

You should move `style` to your CSS file.

Comment: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: sorry this was for the EDIT Form. when there is a value that i need to display else the changed value on form submission